# Stop watching events

Tags: web3js, events

I have activated watching events with `Contract.events.events_name(filter, lastBlock)`, now I need to stop watching this event. I can't find the command in web3 docs. I'm using Web3 version: 1.2.1.
How can I stop watching events?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in the following [github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1587). I suppose it is still up to date.

Quoting the aswer:

> After calling Contract.events.EventName you get a subscription in a
> response. It has unsubscribe method.

However, at this time, it was not fully working. When you test it out, please edit my post to put the correct information.